# How to overwrite my local branch content to my local and remote development branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

We are a team of developers, using git for version control system. I add some changes to the local branch and push it to my local and remote `development` branch.
The other developer, when merge his content to remote development, found my changes. But by mistake my changes were deleted by this developer and he pushed his changes to the remote `development` branch.

When I merged the remote changes to my local `development` branch, I lost my added file, which was deleted by the other developer.

I have reset my branch to the commit when I had my deleted changes. After reset, I found changes but I can not push it or merge it to my `development` branch. I do not want to reset the `master` branch.

Please help, what should I do to overwrite my local changes to my local and remote development branch so that my missing files are added again.

Comment: `git reflog` can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

`git reflog` can help you here.

Your friend should retrieve the state of his `development` branch, before he force pushed, on his computer using `reflog`.

In the `reflog` menu, with each of your states, there will be associated commit hashes. He should `checkout` a new branch, say `development-copy`, using the hash of the state of the `development` branch as it was before he did a `git push -f` to `development`. Now, he should take a look at `git log` on `development-copy`, and create a patch out of all those commits that he wants to add to `development`, then send the patch to your computer, where you can `apply` the patch.